# Offline object storage solution azure blob api compatible

Tags: azure-blob-storage, object-storage, offline-storage

I am looking for the offline storage solution compatible with azure blob storage API for production environment.

Example Minio for AWS S3.

Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator
is for testing purpose i can not used it for production

Answer (score 0):

`Minio` can be used as object storage in Microsoft Azure.

MinIO is an open-source object storage solution.

Yes, Minio can be used as an offline object storage solution in Azure Blob storage with API compatibility by running Minio on an Azure virtual machine or as a managed service.

It can be configured to store data in an Azure Blob storage container.
This allows Minio to access the data in Azure Blob storage and provide a compatible S3-style API to access the data.

And Applications can interact with the Minio instance as if it were an S3 bucket, allowing for offline processing of data stored in Azure Blob storage.

**Minio Features**

It is compatible with the Azure Blob Storage API and can be used in production environments.
It is a high performance, scalability, and compatibility with cloud native tools and technologies.

MinIO supports multi-cloud, on-premises and hybrid cloud deployments, and it is a flexible choice for offline storage.

**Steps to seup Minio**

1. You can install MinIO on a server/ virtual machine / cloud platform like AWS, GCP, Azure or DigitalOcean.
2. Start MinIO with a unique endpoint and access/secret keys to access your data.
3. Create a bucket in MinIO to store your data.
4. You can upload data to MinIO using the MinIO client, S3 API, or the MinIO browser.
5. You can access your data stored in MinIO through the MinIO client, S3 API, or the MinIO browser.
6. MinIO provides features like versioning, lifecycle policies, access controls, and more to manage your data.
7. Use MinIO's built-in monitoring and management tools to monitor the performance and health of your MinIO instance.

[image]

References taken from

[MinIO Client SDK for .NET)](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet)

[MinIO Multi Cloud Object Storage](https://blog.min.io/minio-multi-cloud-azure-marketplace/)

Comment: Thank you but I was looking  for azure api compatible solution not s3 compatible so i will use it for on premise. I am already using minio but i want similar tool which mimic azure storage api i do not want to use azure  service.

Comment: If you are looking for an on-premise solution that is compatible with the Azure Storage API, you can consider using Minio. Minio is an open-source, Amazon S3 compatible object storage solution that can be installed on-premise. It provides a REST API that is compatible with the Azure Storage API, so you can use your existing Azure Storage API code with Minio with minimal modifications

Comment: You can install Minio on a server in your own datacenter and configure it to use your own storage. Minio provides a simple and efficient way to store and retrieve large amounts of data, and its API compatibility with Azure Storage API makes it an attractive alternative to Azure Storage for on-premise scenarios.